# How to end powershell script after the last file in dir

Tags: powershell

Powershell script runs to add letter M in front of all file names. Then it continues to loop after the last file is modified and adds more MMMMs in front of the file name, in a loop. I need it to stop after the first run through all files in Directory.

I tried these three versions. The first with the space in front of M renames all files once but keeps the extra space in front of the name, if I can get rid of the space, it would be what I need:

```
DIR | Rename-Item -NewName {" M" + $_.BaseName + $_.Extension}
```

This version does not have the extra space in front of the M, but keeps adding MMMMs as long as the file name permits more characters.

```
DIR | Rename-Item -NewName {"M" + $_.BaseName + $_.Extension}
```

I also tried putting the letter as a parameter and using Foreach and got the same results as with just letter M in the first two versions:

```
$AL = "M"
Foreach-Object {
    DIR | Rename-Item -NewName {$AL + $_.BaseName + $_.Extension}
}
```

I need the files renamed with an M in front of the name, once and without the extra space. Thank you.

Comment: So, you want to add `M` to the start of the file name _unless_ `M` is already the first character?

Comment: Try: `DIR | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item -NewName ('M' + $_.BaseName + $_.Extension)}`

Comment: @iRon - Your suggestion didn't work for me; while I suspected that it would have the same problem as Erinda's original attempts, it didn't; instead, it simply stopped and prompted me for the mandatory parameter `Path` to `Rename-Item`. `DIR | ForEach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName ('M' + $_.BaseName + $_.Extension)}` _does_ work, however.

Comment: @iRon - I should note, however, that in both the corrected version of your solution _and_ in my solution, the expression `$_.BaseName + $_.Extension` can be replaced by `$_.Name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem
$FileList | Rename-Item -NewName {"M" + $_.BaseName + $_.Extension}
```

Should do the trick. The difference between this and your original is that your original was getting a dynamic list of files; by storing the list of files in a variable, it becomes static, so that the already-renamed files aren't added to the list to be processed.